# Color histogram by individual bins in ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, heatmap

I've got a graph that is a series of histograms.

To emphasize the change in frequency across all the bins in the histrogram, I'm looking to color individual bins by their size (ie. the amount of 'hits' per bin). I'd like to create a heat map effect, so bins with a larger number of hits have a different colour to bins with a smaller number of hits.

What is the parameter associated with bin density/hits?

Cheers!

My current code and what I currently am getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZcQb.png

````
  ggplot( aes(y=branchAngle, color=DBH, fill=DBH)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=1, binwidth = 0.1, size = .1) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=FALSE) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=FALSE) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Branch Angle") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,90,30)) +
  facet_wrap(~factor(DBH), ncol = 16)


p```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter you're looking for would be to access `..count..` as the internally calculated number from `stat_bin()`.  You can also use `..density..`, depending on your preference.  Here's some examples:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# dataset
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  Group1=rnorm(1000, 50, 50),
  Group2=rnorm(1000, 35,67),
  Group3=rnorm(5000, 57,40),
  Group4=rnorm(1000, 75, 60)
)
df <- df %>% gather(group, value)

# plot 1
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=group, alpha=..count..), bins=50) +
  facet_grid(.~group) + coord_flip() + theme_classic()
p
```

[image]

If you want to use the fill aesthetic, here's an example:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=..count..), bins=50) +
  facet_grid(.~group) + coord_flip() + theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='yellow', high='red')
p1
```

[image]